# Insert data to a table via Java GUI

Tags: java, mysql, user-interface

I am getting a bunch of error when I try to insert a new data to the table (Type data for each field and then click submit). It supposed to output the SQL insertion command (exactly the same on that used by Java) in the TextArea. How can I fix this problem? Am I missing something in my code? Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;

import javax.swing.*;

//This GUI interface is a place holder to be finished by students. 

public class InsertPanel extends JPanel{
    private Connection connection = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    public JTextField isbnTextFld;
    public JTextField authorTextFld;
    public JTextField titleTextFld;
    public JTextField priceTextFld;
    public JTextArea textArea;
    public JButton submitBtn;

    public InsertPanel() {
        setBackground(Color.yellow);
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(540, 500));

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));

        JLabel isbnLabel = new JLabel("ISBN: ");
        isbnTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        JLabel authorLabel = new JLabel("Author: ");
        authorTextFld = new JTextField(15);  

        JLabel titleLabel = new JLabel("Title: ");
        titleTextFld = new JTextField(20);

        JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Price: ");
        priceTextFld = new JTextField(10);

        submitBtn = new JButton("Submit");
        ButtonListener buttonListener = new ButtonListener();
        submitBtn.addActionListener(buttonListener);

        textArea = new JTextArea(10, 30);

        p.add(isbnLabel);
        p.add(isbnTextFld);
        p.add(authorLabel);
        p.add(authorTextFld);
        p.add(titleLabel);
        p.add(titleTextFld);
        p.add(priceLabel);
        p.add(priceTextFld);
        p.add(submitBtn);
        p.add(textArea);
        add(p, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(textArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            try {
                connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost/books", "root", "admin");
                statement = connection.createStatement();
                String isbn = isbnTextFld.getText();
                String title = titleTextFld.getText();
                String author = authorTextFld.getText();
                String price = priceTextFld.getText();
                String sql = "Insert('" + (isbn) + "' + '" + (title) + "' +  '" + (author) + "' + '" + (price) 
                    + "')";
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            } catch (SQLException sqlException){
                    sqlException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

create table books
(  isbn char(13) not null primary key,
   author char(30),
   title char(60),
   price float(4,2)
);

insert into books values
  ("0-672-31697-8", "Michael Morgan", "Java 2 for Professional Developers", 34.99),
  ("0-672-31745-1", "Thomas Down", "Installing Debian GNU/Linux", 24.99),
  ("0-672-31509-2", "Pruitt, et al.", "Teach Yourself GIMP in 24 Hours", 24.99),
  ("0-672-31769-9", "Thomas Schenk", "Caldera OpenLinux System Administration Unleashed", 49.99);
```

Thanks for your hepl!!!

Comment: [SQL Tutorial](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/)

Comment: Here is the error: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; che
ck the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '('1-11
1-33344-4' + 'Software Engineering Explained' +  'Dannia Thomas' + '55.56'' at line 1

Comment: could you give you original sql by which you inserted the data?

Comment: @Blip i just updated it in my question above

Comment: `Insert('" + (isbn) + "' + '" + (title) + "' +  '" + (author) + "' + '" + (price) + "')` is not a valid SQL insert statement.

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is that you should **learn more SQL Syntax** before attempting further. I am stating this because the valid SQL insert statement should look like:

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> VALUES (<value1>, <value2>, ....);
```

OR

```
INSERT INTO <table_name> (<column_1>, <column_2>, ...) VALUES (<value1>, <value2>, ....);
```

Also you should try to use `PreparedStatement` instead of `Statement` to dynamically set the values to the statement. And go through JDBC in details.